# How to add a click event inside the form tags

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am creating an angular2 form in typescript using ionic ,

**.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="verify(form)" #form="ngForm">
<ion-input type="text" name="data" #number="ngModel" maxlength='4" [(ngModel)]="digits"></ion-input>
<span *ngIf="number.dirty && form.submitted && form.value.number<4">Enter all numbers</span>
<span *ngIf="number.pristine && form.submitted">Enter number</span>

<button (click)="doAgain()">Click Again</button>

<button type="submit">Verify</button>
</form>
```

**Problem1**: When I click on Click Again button The error message is displayed as Enter number, which i dont want to display also it triggers verify() function.

Update: 
**Problem2**: My requirement is that I only need numbers to enter in the text box and not the alphabets and special characters such as 'a', 'b' , '@'. So with the above implementation the input box is receiving a b c d and @ # $ and 1 2 3 anything. I want to restrict it to number only. I know because I have provided the attribute as type="text" so it acts this way. As I have changed to type="number" I achieved the goal but the number of characters the input field is accepting is more that my maxlength which is 4.

Comment: can you explain your problem 2. like what exactly the number size you need?

Comment: I need only 4 digit numbers, user unable to enter the 5th digit if four digits are completed

Comment: in .ts for every keypress function, you can place a if condition like `( key >= 96 && key <= 105 )`  will allow only numbers.

Comment: can you explain it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding the `type` of the button

```
<button (click)="doAgain()" type='button'>Click Again</button>
```

As `ngSubmit` will be fired on click of any button inside the form group.
To differentiate between `submit` button and other buttons we use this `type`

**[Read here for more information on it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)**

Comment: wow solved, can you tell me answer for problem 2 also so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: @Aditya happy to help you :) anything else you need?

Comment: no I am not available in a teamviewer, I can explain you by editing my answer for problem 2. just a min

Comment: hope you got it?

Comment: Have you got my problem 2 @Aravind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163529/discussion-between-aravind-and-aditya).

Answer (score 0):

You can add type="tel" in input field,

```
<ion-input type="tel" name="data" #number="ngModel" maxlength="4" [(ngModel)]="digits"></ion-input>
```